# Knitr hook for modal

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, bootstrap-modal, knitr

Would it be possible to create a modal based on a hook? Reprex R markdown:

````
  ---
  title: "Modal hook"
  output: html_document
  ---
  
  ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
  library(bsplus)
  library(htmltools)
  library(knitr)
  knit_hooks$set(modal = function(before, options, envir) {
     # ??? 
  })
  ```
  
  This chunk creates a modal window
  
  ```{r, echo=FALSE}
     title <- "Test"
     text = "Some text."
     {
        sink("tmp.md")
        cat('\n```r\nc(1,1)\n```', sep="")
        cat('\n', text)
        sink()
     }
     id <- "m1"
    
    tagList(bs_modal(id = id, title = title, body = includeMarkdown("tmp.md")),
            bs_button(title) %>% bs_attach_modal(id_modal = id))
  ```
````

Would it be possible to create a hook that do the same:

````
  ```{r, modal = TRUE, title = "Test", text = "Some text."}
  c(1,1)
  ```
````

Should also work with plots:

````
  ```{r, modal = TRUE, title = "Test", text = "Some text."}
  plot(1:10)
  ```
````

Basically all the output of the chunk should be put in the modal instead of the document if `modal = TRUE`.

The question is how to define the hook so do as the first chunk.

Comment: I think you need to modify the output hooks for this; one new chunk hook won't be enough.  See https://yihui.org/knitr/hooks/.

Answer (score 3):

The following seems to work

````
  ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
  library(bsplus)
  library(htmltools)
  library(knitr)

  # generate a random id
  opts_hooks$set(modal = function(options) {
    if (isTRUE(options$modal)) {
      options$str_id <- stringi::stri_rand_strings(1, 20)
    }
    options
  })
  
  knit_hooks$set(modal = function(before, options, envir) {
     if (before) {
        paste0('\n<div class="modal fade" id="', options$str_id, '" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="m2-title">',
              '<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">',
              '<div class="modal-content">',
              '<div class="modal-header">',
                 '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>',
                 '<h4 class="modal-title" id="', options$str_id, '-title">', options$title, '</h4>',
              '</div><div class="modal-body">')
     } else {
        paste0('<p>', options$text, '</p></div>',
               '<div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div>',
               '</div></div></div>',
               '<button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#', options$str_id, '">', options$title, '</button><br/>\n')
     }
  })
  ```
````

Modals can now be created using:

````
```{r, modal = TRUE, title = "No code", echo=FALSE}
1:4
```

```{r, modal = TRUE, title = "A plot", text = "Some text."}
plot(1:10)
```
````